# Is there any way that I can save an actual DatabaseReference object to FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to connect 2 nodes by saving in one node the Reference to another node as a value but when I try and do this I get a runtime error:

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)**
```

the code that I tried to run is the following:

```
DatabaseReference svDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("POIs")
                .child("Pub")
                .child("-LIBpQkXx73n3Yt4z0Xn");

DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("References");
dbref.push().setValue(svDbRef, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        Toast.makeText(AddLocation.this, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way -

```
DatabaseReference dbref;
DatabaseReference svDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("POIs").child("Pub").child("-LIBpQkXx73n3Yt4z0Xn").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("References");
        dbref.push().setValue(snapshot, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                Toast.makeText(AddLocation.this, "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {  

    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that ur problem is here:`Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)**`
What is `setWallpaper()` function? Is it yours? Try to rename it

Comment: no it is not mine. It might be from a library that I use, but it doesn't make sense since when I comment out that code it works just fine

Comment: @TudorFilp  Check this out
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1100

Comment: @ForgelArtem well I've already read that and eventhough it's the same runtime error I have not created any class. I'm using the DatabaseReference class which is prefefined.

Comment: @TudorFilp Have u tried to use `DocumentReference ` ? They said that it should work